# How to implement a loop with SQL

Tags: postgresql

The logic I want to implement is:

1. `select id from table_a where ...`
2. Iterate `id`s returned from the first `select`, and delete from table_b:

```sql
delete from table_b where 
  table_a_id = <table_a.id> and id < (
    select min(id) from (select id from table_b where table_a_id = <table_a.id> order by id desc limit 50) as idlist))
```

How to implement this logic with a single SQL statement?

Comment: Are you trying to do batching in chunks of 50? I absolutely don't get what this `min(id)` and `LIMIT` are supposed to achieve.

Comment: What's with the angle brackets in `<table_a.id>`? Is that meant to reference the rows from the first query (`select id from table_a where ...`)?

Comment: **why** do you want to *loop* ?

Comment: @Bergi Each `table_a.id` refer to multiple tuples in `table_b`. Here what I want to do is, for each `table_a.id`, keep most recent 50 tuples in `table_b`, and delete rests.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table_b
where id in (
  select id from table_a
  where ...
);
```

This will firstly run the inner select and capture all ids which meet a specific condition (this is where your where clause comes in). Let's say, for example, the value it returned are (1,2,3,4).

The SQL in essence then becomes:

```
delete from table_b
where id in (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: This is not what I want. As mentioned, table_a's id will be used twice.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple tuples in `table_b` refer to `table_a.id` by `table_a_id`. What I want to do is, for each `table_a.id`, keep the 50 most recent tuples in `table_b`, and delete the rest.

I would write that using a [lateral subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), either

```
DELETE FROM table_b
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT to_drop.id
  FROM table_a
  LATERAL JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_b
    WHERE table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    OFFSET 50
  ) to_drop
)
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table_b
WHERE id NOT IN (
--       ^^^
  SELECT to_keep.id
  FROM table_a
  LATERAL JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM table_b
    WHERE table_b.table_a_id = table_a.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 50
--  ^^^^^
  ) to_keep
)
```

Performance for the two versions might depend on whether there are more rows to keep or more to delete. In either case, make sure that `table_b` has an index on `table_a_id, id`.